# How to change colum name and overwrite the data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

There are 2 data frame.
df1 is the original data and df2 is the output data (changed data) - but the original columns are displayed as they are.

I'd like to change column name and value (df2 → df1).

Please help me.

1. Change "ch_id, ch_age, ch_score" name to id, age, score
2. Change value df2 -> df1 (age, score)

Example:

```
id <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
age <- c(24, 28, 31, 25, 27, 22, 29)
sex <- c("male", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female")
score <- c(90, 80, 85, 75, 95, 80, 70)

df1 <- data.frame(id, age, sex, score, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1

ch_id <- c("1", "2")
ch_age <- c(50, 40)
ch_score <- c(80, 80)

df2 <- data.frame(ch_id, ch_age, ch_score, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 <- data.frame(id=ch_id, age=ch_age, score=ch_score, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

To change `df2`'s `id,age,score` into `df1`'s `id,age,score`:

```
df2 <- df1[,-3]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I`d like to change the value after the making data.frame (T.T) is there good solution ??  I want the df2 value including original value (df1) / overwrite changed value

Comment: original column: id age sex score
original row: 7 lines  
your logic is displayed only id age score (changed value),
I`d like to display original columns & rows

Comment: original columns and rows? You mean `df1`? If you want to change the entries of the frame, e.g. for `id` you can simply `df1$id <- c(50, 40)`.  Could you clarify what you'd like the final output to be?

Comment: ```
original columns: df1 (its correct)
expected output
- column: id age sex score
- row: 7 lines data with changed data (according to example it is age, score)
```

Comment: - column: id age sex score

Comment: - row: 7 lines data with changed data (according to example it is age, score)

Comment: What 'changed data' and what example? Your `df2` is missing a sex column, so you can't combine simply with `rbind(df1, df2)`.

Comment: Yes I know. df2 is changed value, exactly I want to update the original data with changed value (df2 = age & score) Sorry to difficult explanation

Comment: Okay, but you don't know the sex for df2. So do something like this, `df2 <- data.frame(id=ch_id, age=ch_age, sex=rep(NA,length(ch_id), score=ch_score), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and then `df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)`

Comment: wow I think it is helpful. I will run it !!!

Comment: owe T.T algae. thanks you helped me but i wasn`t work maybe I didn`t give you exactly what i want. so i added question 1more time please refer below url.  \ https://stackoverflow.com/q/71221647/18062678

Comment: You need to give a reproducible example. _Write down what you want as an output and include it in your post_.